# How to Put File Information into MIPS array?

Tags: assembly, mips

Say I have a file with the following numbers separated by spaces:

```
5 9 4 2 6
```

With MIPS, how can I put this in an array such that (C++ equivalent) array[0] = A, array[1] = B, etc.?

Comment: Do you want to parse this from a file at run-time, or can you assemble it into a static array with `.long 5,9,4,2,6`?  If you have to parse it, is it guaranteed that numbers are always single-digit?

Comment: Parse at run time, and they're always single digit

Comment: Ok, then you don't really need to "parse" it, you can just use `lbu` from fixed byte offsets into a buffer after reading the file contents, and convert ASCII digits to integer.